# CSS Left-side and Right-side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning css right now so you may know what kind of problems are trying to blow my mind... hahaha

Okey, I'm trying to separate my web in two divs like this:

[image]

and the intention is that the right-side realize there is something at his left.

Left Side:

```
.left-side {
  background: url('../img/mesh.png') #333;
  position: relative; 
  top: 0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Right-side: Here's the problem

```
.right-side {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  float: left; /* Trying to detect something at my left */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Both have relative positions because I read they should, maybe I'm wrong...

Just for giving you some context, on the left-side would be a navigation bar and on the right side would be all the grid and main content.

I'm using bootstrap framework for creating the grid on the right-side but the problem is that all the div's do not take their parent as a reference.

```
<html>
<head>
   .....
</head>
<body>
   <div class="left-side">
      <!-- Navbar -->
   </div>
   <div class ="right-side">
      <div class ="container-fluid">
         <!-- etc -->
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading this. I would try to fix this by my own, some help would be well recieved

Comment: Having `top: 0px;` on a relatively-positioned element doesn’t do anything. Did you mean to maybe make them both `position: absolute;`? (The left bar would have to have a fixed [as in something that can be specified as one number with one unit] width for that to work, though.)

Comment: Thanks, the absolute is working on the left-side but what about the right one, I gave it a left margin but I think that there is another better way..

Comment: A left margin is perfectly fine too, but don’t use it with `width: 100%`. (I would personally set `position: absolute; left: <whatever>; top: 0; right: 0;`, though.) But if Bootstrap provides ways to do this (apparently it does) then go with those instead.

Comment: Thanks :) Constructive and straight to the point, thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use what Bootstrap gives you, which is span classes. What about something like this?

```
<html>
<head>
   .....
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="span3">
          <!-- left side -->
       </div>
       <div class="span9">
          <!-- right side -->
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm wrong but the span9 will not be limiting the pixels? Sorry I don't know how to explain myself well(not in english). I mean I want to give right-side everything but what left-side takes.

Comment: Yes, that is how it will work when you use `row-fluid`. Try it and see if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's working haha. I change the first span for span1 and the second for span11. It is right?. Apart from that this is a big big keep it simple stupid! :)

Comment: Yes, you can change the size of the span to whatever you want, as long as they add up to 12.

Comment: Done :) Will not happen again

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need position relative.  Usually the best use for that is when you need to position something absolutely inside it - that is, relative to the box you're calling relative.

To use the floats like this, you need to set the widths, and they can't be set to 100%.  Doing that means they're taking up as much room as their container, which in this case looks like the whole screen.  That means the right div is going to wrap below the left one, since it can't fit next to it.  Start out by setting the left to width 100px and the right to width 500px, or something like that, and play with it from there.

And make the left float:left as was pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to left-side. So, thet element goes to left.

Comment: This breaks with `width: 100%`. It also won’t span a correct width without it.